# single pass data transformation using dask to do same as basic pandas example

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Im trying to understand how [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dataframe-methods) can help me do data transformation on a huge dataset. The task I need to perform is as the example below in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                    'VAL1': [0,1,4,1,4,1,1,1,4],
                    'VAL2': [0,3,4,3,4,3,3,3,4],
                    'VAL3': [4,3,4,3,4,3,3,3,4],
                    'VAL4': [4,3,4,3,4,3,3,3,4]})
vals1 = ['VAL1', 'VAL2']
vals2 = ['VAL3', 'VAL4']
pdf[vals1] = pdf[vals1].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > 1 else 0)
pdf[vals2] = pdf[vals2].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x < 4 else 0)
pdf['ANY1'] = pdf[vals1+vals2].apply(lambda row: 1 if sum(row) > 0 else 0,axis=1)
pdf['ONES'] = 1
pdf.groupby(['ID']).sum()
```

When I start out using:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.from_pandas(pdf, chunksize=9)
df...
```

I get stuck right away when trying to transform the data im multiple columns and adding more columns all in  a single pass.

So my question is how can I recreate the example from pandas dask and a single pass over the data?

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt to do it a single pass:

```
In [125]: pd.concat([df.ID, (df[vals1] > 1), (df[vals2] < 4)], axis=1).assign(ONES=1).groupby('ID').sum()
Out[125]:
    VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  VAL4  ONES
ID
A    1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0     2
B    0.0   4.0   4.0   4.0     4
C    2.0   2.0   0.0   0.0     2
D    0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0     1
```

I don't know yet how to calculate the `ANY1` column as it based on previous changes...

Comment: Nice start, i did some more work on it and came up with the answer below. However im not sure how this is executed in dask, or if it is the fastes way...

Answer (score 0):

Given MaxUs answere I came up with the following, however I do not know if this is done in a single pass with dask??

```
import pandas as pd
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                    'VAL1': [0,1,4,1,4,1,1,1,4],
                    'VAL2': [0,3,4,3,4,3,3,3,4],
                    'VAL3': [4,3,4,3,4,3,3,3,4],
                    'VAL4': [4,3,4,3,4,3,3,3,4]})
vals1 = ['VAL1', 'VAL2']
vals2 = ['VAL3', 'VAL4']
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
df = dd.from_pandas(pdf, chunksize=9)
dd.concat([df.ID, (df[vals1] > 1), (df[vals2] < 4)], axis=1).assign(ANY1 = lambda data: data[vals1+vals2].apply(lambda x: 1 if sum(x) > 0 else 0, axis=1), ONES = 1).groupby(['ID']).sum().astype(np.uint32).compute()
```